# IndexedDB Database backup/ restore scenarios

Tags: performance, progressive-web-apps, indexeddb

I have a question about `indexedDB` and  `Dexie.js` library, for restoring and backing up databases and their performance improvements. lets imagine we have at least a 2 GB database (for offline map data) and they have a (key,value) structure which Key can be an string and value is blob (image or binary vector data).
So in my scenario users select a database and my web application should start to download that database for offline access. So what approach do you think gives me the best performance in this case? Since I have to download the backup and restore them and for 2GB and a few million records it can be a performance challenge. I have done similar thing before for sqlite databases but I only needed to download the db file and connect to it. Here I have to restore IndexedDB after downloading which seems to be problematic. So I can break my problem in several sub issues:

Firstly How can I make those databases in the first place?

And then, how can I restore those backups? Is there any high-performance method to do so?

Does the key data type (String or Integer) has effect on the performance of IndexedDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean with "restore" but I think you mean to import data into IndexedDB? Or did you mean that IndexedDB is the backup and "restore" for putting it back into another database?

I base the rest of my answer on the assumption that "restore" is importing data into indexeddb.

The only way to know how the system would perform when adding millions of key/value (blob) based rows would be to test it. I would suggest you import the rows in chunks of maybe 1000 each and show a progress bar for each imported chunk. Use bulkAdd() or bulkPut() methods to import each chunk. Make sure not to do the entire import in a single transaction because that could probably starve the system and block indexeddb for too long. But by using the bulk-methods each chunk would use a single transaction at least (which is also important - one transaction per 1000 records would probably be fine - but if you test this, try different chunk sizes to find the optimal speed!).

Also don't know what the user can expect in terms of waiting time. Can it be performed in the background while user can use your app in online mode? If so, it the user could probably accept longer import-time than if the user would have to wait for the entire data to be imported.

You would also need to look at the [StorageManager API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageManager) and ask your user for permission to store large amounts of durable data. You can read page about it [in dexie docs](https://dexie.org/docs/StorageManager) also.

You would probably want a background worker to fetch the data and perform the bulk operations - create a service worker that does the job. Either use response.blob() and pass it to [dexie-export-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dexie-export-import). You could also try the [ReadableStream api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams) to download chunks of data. Letting a worker do this download and import will perform faster and not affect the application performance while importing.

Dexie-export-import does almost exactly what I am suggesting here - imports the rows in chunks into indexeddb, but if using it you would need to let your service endpoint send JSON that is compatible with dexie-export-import where blobs are Baset64 encoded. But since your data is only keys and blobs, you could benefit from having your own binary format and do the bulkAdd() yourself without this addon.

Regarding your last question: to my knowledge, there wouldn't be so much difference between using number or strings as keys. Long strings would be slower but short strings probably perform equal to numbers (correct me someone if this isn't true!). You would need to test to really know.

If you will perform some test on this, please let me know what your results were ;)

Comment: @david-sahlander, Thanks for your help. I really appreciate your help and will do as you advice. I will keep you posted about the performance.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com
Size: 1825
Last modified: Mon Jan 09 2023 15:34:46 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Open connections: 0
Paths:
C:\Users\KuldeepChopra\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\IndexedDB\https_stackblitz.com_0.indexeddb.leveldb
C:\Users\KuldeepChopra\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\IndexedDB\https_stackblitz.com_0.indexeddb.blob
Force close Download ?

Comment: I cleared the storage from the application tab, but I have these files C:\Users\KuldeepChopra\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\IndexedDB\https_stackblitz.com_0.indexeddb.blob  , so the question is how to import/restore